# Issue getting files in with FPDI/FPDF

Tags: php, pdf

I am having issues getting an image into my PDF.  I have a form, and on it I have two upload fields.  The user can upload a PDF, or an image.  When the file is uploaded, it is saved in my temp folder without an extension.  I pass my class two things: $fileData, which is the url to the file, and inputArray which is an array of other data from the form (name, address, etc).

My code is like so

```
private $tplidx;

public function __construct($fileData, $inputArray) {
    $pdf = new \FPDI();
    $count = 10;
    $pdf->AddPage('P');
    $pdf->SetFontSize(20);

    foreach($inputArray as $input) {
        $pdf->SetXY(50, $count);
        $pdf->Write(1, $input);
        $count = $count + 10;
    }

    foreach($fileData as $name => $extension){
        if($extension == "application/pdf") {
            $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($name);
            for($i=0; $i<$pagecount; $i++){
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $this->tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i+1);
                $pdf->useTemplate($this->tplidx, 10, 10, 200);
            }
        } else {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $filetype = explode("/",$extension);
            $pdf->Image($name.'.'.$filetype[1],30,120,25);
        }
    }

    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');
}
```

The first foreach adds the inputs from the field to a page, this works fine.
The next foreach next checks if its a pdf, and if it is, it adds it to another page in the PDF.  This also works fine.

My problem is in the else, because I am appending the files extension, I get the error

> Can't open image file

If I remove the extension part, I get the error

> Image file has no extension and no type was specified

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image type in the `$type` parameter of the [Image()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) method.